# Ignore Unique Constraint and still insert other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think I want the semantics of both `UNIQUE` and `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`.

I have an `INSERT` query that looks over recent data and inserts a unique key-value pair. It runs often and takes seconds at most.

I have another `INSERT` query that looks at all data and inserts unique key-value pairs. It takes minutes to run and probably finds nothing to do, except it will sometimes see the same data as the recent query, and will decide to insert the same pair.

I've implemented a `UNIQUE` constraint, so that's not a problem in itself, but I'd like other records determined by the long-running query to be inserted irrespective of the duplicates.

Both queries do explicitly have a clause similar to

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Key, Value From TargetTable TT
   WHERE TT.Key = Result.Key AND TT.Value = Result.Value)
```

Comment: if i understand you correctly, may be a you are looking for a unique filtered index on `Key, Value` with only recent filtered data

Comment: Could you break this into two separate tables that the two different processes populate and then a view that gives the illusion that only one row exists even if that row exists in both tables (preferring the row from the fast process)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to split the second query into two so that I now have three queries:

- Quick 15 minute past query running every 30 seconds.
- Nearly as quick query looking back to midnight UTC; may have duplicate key failures but retrying won't take long; runs every 2 minutes.
- Slow query reviewing all data, but ignoring the current UTC day; won't have duplicate key failures; runs twice a day.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like MySQL's `INSERT IGNORE`.  I don't believe this functionality exists in SQL Server.  Your specific problem appears to be updates on this (or another table) that occur during the updating process, introducing duplicate keys.

One option is to put a lock on the table during this operation, not allowing any other operations.  That is probably not feasible given the time frame for the lock.

Another option is to take the long running query and stash the results into a temporary table.  Then, do the inserts from this table, one at a time, capturing and ignoring any violations of the unique constraint.